# How to build non js file using babel?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In a `nodejs` `express.js` application, and trying to build the app using `babel` for cross browser compatibility.

`package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
       "start": "node dist/app.js",
       "build": "babel src -d dist"
}
```

On running `npm build` and check my build folder everything builds correctly except my non-js files like [.html,.css,.ejs]. At the moment just copied those file to the build folder in their respective sub directories and everything works fine.

I have even tried
 `"build": "babel src -d dist --ignore *.css,*.ejs,*.png,*.jpg"`

Is there a way to do this in a better way instead of copying the non-js files. Thanks in advance any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i  am not using web pack I just have .babelrc file

Comment: `--ignore *.css,*.html,*.ejs` should work. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#ignore-files

Comment: i have tried that before but when i check  my dist directory the ignored files are not there.I have a  css file somewhere in my src directory.It would be easier for me to have that same file in the dist folder once the build process is over

Comment: I have written an article about using Babel with Node.js/ Express.js

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-es6-babel-nodejs-harshal-yeole/

Comment: The `--ignore` flag keeps the given files out of the build. That isn't what you want. You might try the `--copy-files` flag though.

Comment: @Adam i have tried  `"build": "babel src -d dist --copy-files *.css,*.ejs,*.png,*.jpg"`
  but there  is an error  ` *.css,*.ejs,*.png,*.jpg doesn't exist`

Comment: The `--copy-files` flag doesn't take arguments. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#copy-files

Comment: @Adams thank you .That just solved my issue

Comment: Great! I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 25):

If you have non-JavaScript files in the source directory that should be automatically copied to the output location when the command is run, simply add the [`--copy-files`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#copy-files) flag.

```
babel src -d dist --copy-files
```

The flag doesn't take any arguments and will copy all non-JS files over.